# how to stop keydown function after click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

i have js code when i press key 38, 40 13 those function works respectively.
but what i want to do is ,when i **click** this button **keydown function block** will be disable,
and when i **hover** this button this **keydown function block** will be enable.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode == 38) { 
   verticalSlideDown();
   //console.log("pressed key for Down : "+e.keyCode);
}
if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
   verticalSlideUp();
   //console.log("pressed key for Up: "+e.keyCode);
}
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var div= $(".scroll-inner-container");
    //console.log("pressed key for stop : "+e.keyCode);
   div.stop();
}
});
```

this is my html button:

```
<button class="keyboard-btn">click here</button>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery `on()` and `off()` to add and remove event handlers dynamically: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 3):

Just create a flag.

Enabled on hover, disabled on click.

```
var controlsEnabled = false;

$(myButton).hover(function () {
    controlsEnabled = true;
});

$(myButton).on('click', function () {
    controlsEnabled = false;
});

$(document).keydown(function (event) {

    if (controlsEnabled)
    {
        // rest of code here
    }

});
```

Comment: thank you very much @Lars ..! it works.but i do not know it is problem or not with click event.when i click this button...at the same time cursor keep hover over this button.for that hover event always be true...what can i do for that..? have any idea.

Comment: The hover event will override the click event since it gets called repeatably, as opposed to the click event, which gets called once per click.  I don't know how to solve that problem without changing the setup.

Comment: how can i use click event.first click for enable,and second click for disable.this function......?